# What is the "space" parameter in std::align?

Tags: c++, alignment, buffer

In https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align, there's a `space` parameter that's the "buffer size." What is meant by buffer size here?

Is it like the amount of space you have to use to create the designed alignment? If it is, why is it needed?

Answer (score 1):

It is an input output parameter. So it will do 2 things:

1. Tell the function how much space is available, so if alignment would overrun the buffer, the function fails:

> The function modifies the pointer only if it would be possible to fit the wanted number of bytes aligned by the given alignment into the buffer. If the buffer is too small, the function does nothing and returns nullptr.

2. Function can output how much space is left after alignment, so you can string calls together. This is useful if you were writing some sort of aligned allocator.

Comment: Since it is also an "input" parameter, how do we acquire the amount of space available prior to calling the function?

Comment: @westcoaststudent You created the buffer. So you know how much space you created it with.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider why you would want to align a pointer.

Think about a case where you have a range of memory that has been allocated for you to create objects into. This is called a memory buffer. The size of the buffer is the number of bytes from the start of the range to its end. Each object has a type. Each type has an alignment requirement. Objects of that type can only be created in addresses aligned to the required byte boundary.

Let's say the first address of the memory range isn't aligned to the byte boundary that is required by the type of the object that you want to create. In such case, you cannot create the object at the beginning of the memory range. That's where you need `std::align`. It adjusts the given pointer to the next address that is aligned, which is the first address where the object can be created.

To do that, you only need to know the address and the alignment. But you also need to know whether the object can fit inside of your memory range after the alignment. For example, if you have 16 bytes of memory and you want to create an object of 16 bytes, but the first address isn't aligned to the 4 byte boundary so if you create the object starting from the adjusted (aligned) address, then it would overflow the memory range by the number of adjusted bytes. So in order to know that, we also pass the `size` of the object and the size of the memory `space`. If the object won't fit, then `std::align` returns null.

We may also want to create more than one object into that memory buffer, so we will need to know how much the pointer had been adjusted so that we can find out where we can create the next object. That is why `space` is a non-const reference argument. The function deducts the number of aligned bytes from `space` if the object fits.

Comment: How do we determine how much `space` is available?

Comment: @westcoaststudent You just have to know it. If you don't know the size of your buffer, then you can't do anything with it. How do  you know that you have a buffer in the first place?

Comment: For example, if you use a global allocation function, then you tell the allocator how many bytes you want. You know how many bytes there are by virtue of knowing how many bytes you asked for.